# Converting a tf.Tensor from one int value to another via lookup

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have the following labels: `[15, 76, 34]`.  I am trying to map them to be `[0, 1, 2]` inside of a `tf.data.Dataset` using the [`map`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#map) function.

So I need a function that can do the following:

```py
def relabel(label: tf.Tensor) -> tf.Tensor:
    # TODO: convert 15 --> 0, 76 --> 1, 34 --> 2
    return new_label

dataset: tf.data.Dataset
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x, y: x, relabel(y))
```

I am having a tough time working with `tf.Tensor`, can anyone complete this implementation?

Comment: Do you need those value to be mapped back afterwards, like 0 -> 15, 1 -> 76, etc? Otherwise, you can simply use tf.unique

Comment: I don't need to reverse map, only one-way.  If you wouldn't mind posting a solution using `tf.unique`, would be interested to see!  So one calls `tf.unique` up-front to get the unique indices, but then I am not sure inside the `relabel` mapping function how to access those indices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `lookup` table that assigns the old labels to new labels:

```
label_tensor = tf.constant([15, 76, 34], tf.int32)
new_label_tensor = tf.constant([0, 1, 2])
table = tf.lookup.StaticHashTable(
    tf.lookup.KeyValueTensorInitializer(label_tensor, new_label_tensor, key_dtype=tf.int32,value_dtype=tf.int32), -1)
```

checking for inputs:

```
X = tf.constant([0.1, 0.2, 0.3], dtype=tf.float32)
Y = tf.constant([15, 76, 34], dtype=tf.int32)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X, Y))
```

relabeling can be done by,

```
def relabel(x, y):
    return x, table.lookup(y)
dataset = dataset.map(relabel)
```

Outputs,

```
 for x, y in dataset:
    print(x.numpy(), y.numpy())
 #outputs
 0.1 0
 0.2 1
 0.3 2
```

Comment: This is perfect, works and is integrated into my code!  Answers like this keep the world going round.  One note is I found my labels start out as `int64`, so I ended up just removing all `dtype` specifications (instead relying on defaults) from the lookup table.